# Installed OpenMPI library, but cannot use mpicc command in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, configure, openmpi

I am following openmpi install file.

Firstly, I am a normal user in this linux system. I do not have rights to access /usr/local . If I configure with:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

make will complain about permission.

Therefore, I put the place to install in some other directory (let's call it directory 'A'), and then `make install` .

I got all the files in the bin and such. I got mpic++, mpicc, etc. in the bin folder and such, in the directory 'A'.

Now, the thing is when I need to compile other programs:

```
Compiling MPI Applications
==========================

MPI applications should be compiled using the Open MPI "wrapper"
compilers:

C programs:   mpicc your-code.c
C++ programs: mpiCC your-code.cc    or
              mpic++ your-code.cc   (for case-insensitive filesystems)
```

This is from the INSTALL file. The thing is bash complains that mpicc command is not found when I type in "mpicc".

OpenMPI is a dependency for the other programs I am trying to compile, and they invoke OpenMPI by using 'mpicc' command.

What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your folder `A` needs to be on your `PATH` environment variable. In bash, you would do:

```
export PATH=/path/to/my/folder/A/bin:$PATH
```

which will let you just type `mpicc`. Alternatively, you can use the full path as your command:

```
/path/to/my/folder/A/bin/mpicc myFile.c
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have write access to the default prefix file tree `/usr/local/` you should `./configure` with an explicit writable prefix, e.g.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/pub
```

of course, you could `mkdir $HOME/pub` then should add `$HOME/pub/bin` to your `PATH`

Comment: The `install` target in makefiles, created by `autoconf`'s `configure` script, usually creates the target directory if it doesn't exist.