# Getting OpenMPI to work on Mac:

Tags: openmpi

I have installed OpenMPI via MacPorts on my OSX system (running Version 10.8.3). I found the C wrapper compiler in /opt/local/lib/openmpi/bin/mpicc, and

```
/opt/local/lib/openmpi/bin/mpicc test.c
```

compiles normally. Following the ideas in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909432/installed-openmpi-library-but-cannot-use-mpicc-command-in-linux) post, I issued the following command

```
PATH=$PATH:~/opt/local/lib/openmpi/bin
```

which I thought would allow me to compile with

```
mpicc test.c
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
-bash: mpicc: command not found
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just kidding: I should've used

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/lib/openmpi/bin
```

rather than

```
PATH=$PATH:~/opt/local/lib/openmpi/bin
```

Comment: This resets for me every time I close the terminal, is there a more permanent solution?

Comment: I found the permanent solution: https://web.archive.org/web/20130704032716/https://hathaway.cc/2008/06/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x/